# Questions with tags containing accent marks break those on editing

Tags: bug, tags, edits, mobile-web, localization

Few days ago I was editing [a question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24213/1674) in Spanish.SE using the mobile site. It has three tags: [traducción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/traducci%C3%B3n), [solicitud-de-término](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-t%C3%A9rmino) and [psicología](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psicolog%C3%ADa) and, as you can see, all of them contain accent marks.

When I was about to submit the edit, I noticed that the tags were completely broken:

[image]

I thought that I would not have any problem while submitting the revision, since the tags had not been changed. But no, even that was impossible, since the system would see those as wrong tag names.

What I had to do is to remove all the tags and start typing them from scratch, so the system would understand them.

I also reported this happening on Stack Overflow en español almost one year ago: [Las etiquetas con tildes se reproducen incorrectamente en la versión móvil](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2221/83)

This is the full view:

[image]